# binary to buffer in C

Tags: c, file, buffer

I'm trying to fix this problem, but i dont know why it doesn't work! In my main function I'm getting the name of the binary file (argv[1])! Now I'm trying to get the content into a char Array (Buffer) to handle the content in another function. But i dont know why I get a 0 when i printf "readed" and why theres is no output when i printf the buffer!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//only allowed libaries



int readBin (char *bin_file_name, char *txt_file_name)
{

  int readed = 0;
  FILE *input = fopen(bin_file_name, "rb");
  int file_size = 0;
  char *buffer;

  //get Filesize 
  fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
  file_size = ftell(input);
  rewind(input);

  //Allocate memory for buffer
  buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*file_size);

  //Fill Buffer
  readed = fread(buffer,file_size,0, input);

  printf("%i\n", readed);
  printf("%s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: You should check to make sure that your file is actually being opened. Simple if statement that opens the file like `if( (input = fopen(bin_file_name, "rb")) == NULL){ printf("unable to open file"); exit(1);}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
readed = fread(buffer,file_size,0, input);
```

should be

```
readed = fread(buffer,file_size,1, input);
//                              ^
```

Your current code requests to read 0 blocks of `file_size` bytes.

You still won't be able to print the contents of `file_size`.  The `%s` format specifier expects a null terminated string but `file_size` is a block of binary data.  You'll need to allocate one byte extra and add a `\0` in that extra byte if you want to have a try at printing as a string.  Or you could iterate through the memory using the `%02x` format specifier to print as hex instead.

As an aside,

```
buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*file_size);
```

would be better as

```
buffer = malloc(file_size);
```

(You shouldn't cast the return from `malloc` and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1)

and you should `free` this memory later in your program.

Comment: Thank you! Works so far! Now I can see an unreadble char! But there should be more chars!

Comment: Ok! Thank you! So far i understand that this problem only happens, when i try to printf it, but in my buffer everything is, like it should be! So it should be possible to handle all the chars in the buffer, because the task isn't to print it (I've just done this, to look if it works), the task is to write it in an own txt file!

Comment: That's correct, the contents of your buffer are fine.  They're just not suitable for viewing as a string.